# How to implement a tabbed viewpager without actionbar in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I want to implement a tabbed view pager where the tabs are not part of the action bar. 
What is the correct way of doing this since it doesn't seem supported by standard.

So far I have been using the following approach and it seems like it's been so much more effort than it should be that it bothers me:

- Create horizontally oriented linear layout to act as tab bar view
- Create individual tab views to populate tab bar along with styling
- Create custom ongesturelistener for left and right swipe to go between tabs
- Create animations for sliding-in/out upon swiping (fragment transactions)
- Create animations for the tab bar upon swiping

This seems like it's way too much work when there is a viewpager and tabbar built in. It seems though this "proper" approach is limited to only being used in conjunction with the actionbar. Can anyone provide a simple example of what I am trying to achieve? (see following picture for clarity).

[image: photo for clarity of the type of thing I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: Could you use something like this library? I believe you can put the indicator anywhere: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I would expect #3 and #4 to come for free with ViewPager (that's what it does), and that you would have to do #1 #2 and #5 on your own (or use a library).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build a ViewPager bundled with an ActionBar, they are both independent views.

You can simply hide the ActionBar on that activity doing something like:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
mActionBar.hide();
```

Although it's an ugly solution you can do that to test your code. I would suggest either add a Theme to that specific Activity without an ActionBar (something like Theme.Material.NoActionBar) - not sure it's the correct name of the theme, but you get the idea.

Not sure I answered your question accordingly, but if not please show us some code.

Answer (score -1):

You just add a viewpager with a pager tab strip.  Plenty examples out there.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyTabsPagerAdapter(
            fm, tabsArray);

    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);




<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/default_screen_bg"
android:minWidth="1000dp">

put your image here

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```